# How to stop my producer container/API in spring-integration with kafka extension

Tags: spring-integration, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I am using  spring integration with kafka producer API. I want to stop my Producer API when I got some MessageException or ProducerException.

In consumer (normal spring-kafka) I am using ConsumerAwareListenerErrorHandler to stop my Listener easily.

In a same way I am looking for some handlers in SI to stop my producer container.

Created an error channel and getting all my exceptions into that channel, but couldn't find a way to stop my container. Tried something with SmartLifeCycle, but no luck.

Here my Bean to publish messages to Kafka topic

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow hanldeKafka() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(sendToKafkaChannel)
            .handle(
                    kafkaMessageHandler(producerFactory, topicName),
                    e -> e.id("myProducer"))
            .get();
}


public KafkaProducerMessageHandlerTemplateSpec<String, String> kafkaMessageHandler(
        ProducerFactory<String, String> producer, String topic) {
    return Kafka
            .outboundChannelAdapter(producer)
            .sync(true)
            .headerMapper(kafkaHeaderMapper())
            .messageKey(m ->  {
                try {
                Message value = jsonObjectMapper.fromJson(m.getPayload(), Message.class);
                return value.getlId();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.toString());
                    throw new MessagingException(m);
                }
            })
            //.partitionId(m -> 10)
            .topicExpression("headers[kafka_topic] ?: '" + topic + "'")
            .configureKafkaTemplate(t -> t.id("kafkaTemplate:" + topic));
}
```

Can anyone suggest, how to add some handlers/controllers to stop the producer container/API.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "producer container" - there is no such thing.

To permanently close the `Producer` (s) call `reset()` on the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`.

Comment: Hi Gary, 
Thank you very much for your reply. I am aware of this reset() which would close my producer permanently. 

However I am looking for something similar to MessageListenerContainer where we can play around with the listener container using start() and stop() methods.

Do we have anything like this to start and stop my Kafka Message producer thread. 

My intention is not to stop my producer permanently. Instead I want to stop publishing the messages to my topic in case of any issues (eg: my upstream interface is down or any other runtime exceptions)

Comment: There is no equivalent of a listener container on the producer side. When you want to publish a message, we get a producer from the factory; the default factory caches a single producer used by all callers (unless transactions are being used). It's not clear what "thread" you are talking about. You will need logic in your producer code to not publish under those conditions.

Comment: Thanks agian @Gary Russell for your valuable inputs.  Is there any specific intention for not having such equivalent of a listener container on the producer side?

Comment: ? On the consumer side, the natural way to use the Consumer client is to call `poll()` to get records. Spring has the notion of a `MessageListenerContainer` where the user just provides a listener bean and the container takes care of all the infrastructure and calls the listener method for each record returned by the `poll()`, in a message-driven fashion. There are message listener containers for multiple technologies, JMS, RabbitMQ, etc, etc. There simply is no need for that on the producer side since you send one record at a time. It is entirely passive, except the client's heartbeat thread.

Comment: If you reset the producer factory, the producer will be closed; a new one will be created the next time you `send()` a record. It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to start/stop publishing messages to kafka without restarting my application...I have two different apps (Publihser, Subscriber) where in my subscriber app, I am able to stop/start my subscriber programatically without restarting the application. 
Appreciate your prompt responses.... :)

Comment: But thst's completely under your control. You need to stop whatever is the stimulus for publishing. i.e. what in your application calls the publisher.